# Threading and WPF's Binding

Tags: wpf, multithreading, wpftoolkit

**The Situation**

I'm getting the following inconstant behavior on my application: One in about 20 executions, a WPFToolkit's `DataGrid` which is bound to a `DataTable` won't render all the rows, missing anything between 1 to 3 of the whole 4 rows that were expected.

**Inner Workings**

- The `DataGrid` is bound to a `DataTable`, **D1**, which is a property of a custom class, **C1**.
- When the user stimulates the view, we must retrieve the data from the back-end, which can take time. To do so, we create a thread (actually, we use `BackgroundWorker` for that but there seems to be no difference from using one or the other), which runs a method, **M1**, that opens the connection and request the data. The thread is used to avoid having an unresponsive application.
- M1 retrieves data and stores it on a DTO first. After that, he asks **C1** to clear it's table. **C1** does so (by calling a `D1.Clear()`) and raises `NotifyPropertyChanged()` (from the thread).
- M1 passes the new backend's `DataTable` to **C1**, which inserts row by row into **D1**. After finishing inserting the rows, **C1** raises `NotifyPropertyChanged()`. The thread exits.

So, in other words, I clear the table, notify WPF, insert the data, notify WPF and exit.

In my view, as long as the last Notify is correctly consumed from the UI, it should *always* show all the rows.

Besides the `DataTable`, there are a large number of properties (mostly strings and int) being update and thus notified. We have **not** observed this behavior in any other case, only with the `DataTable`.

I know this goes deep into WPF mechanisms for binding, but I hope anyone can shed a light here. **Any** information about WPF binding or multi-threading with WPF is welcome.

Comment: Are you dispatching to the UI thread when M1 asks C1 to make changes to D1?

Comment: @KentBoogaart: No! The changes are made in the thread itself. However, after the changes are made, C1 raises the NotifyPropertyChanged. It's my belief that this should be enough to guarantee that the UI would be refreshed with the correct content. Is it true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx) pre dates WPF and thus doesn't implement [INotifyCollectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) which is how WPF monitors for collection changes.  You have two options:

1. Replace the existing DataTable with a new DataTable (after you have set the rows).  Then fire the property changed notification.
2. Change from a DataTable to an ObservableCollection.  The collection will fire a change notification anytime you change the list of items.  (Note it will not fire if you change the contents of one of the items already in the list)

INotifyPropertyChanged notifies when the property has changed, not when the internal state (be it a property or collection) have changed.  When you fire the Property Changed event WPF only rebinds the controls if the property is a different object from the last time it bound the data.  This keeps it from refreshing the whole screen when you only change one property several layers down in an object graph.

Comment: David, I was notifying only *after* I had loaded the rows. I don't need to notify the screen during the addition, since the application only retrieves the data from a user stimulus. Anyway, you say that WPF only updates the screen if it thinks the data is different. How he does that?

Comment: @BrunoBrant, WPF knows if the data is different by keeping a reference to the data it is already bound to and comparing it to the new reference. You can read more about it [here](http://www.lhotka.net/weblog/CommentView,guid,06f305de-ec32-4e20-b042-171b58f305ae.aspx) and [here](http://kentb.blogspot.com/2007/03/beware-datacontext-and-equals.html). There is another option I forgot to mention. Set the actual property to null before you fire the first PropertyChanged notification, then set it back to your data table before you fire the final one.

Comment: but I don't change the DataContext, I just update one property of the object. Does Equal() is still used to determine change? My DataContext is not the DataTable but an object which has a property that is a DataTable.

Comment: @BrunoBrant DataContext is a property too.  The check applies for all binding because it uses reflection and is an expensive operation, especially in the case of a collection of data.

Answer (score 2):

Are you loading the new data into the *same* DataTable instance that's already bound to the DataGrid?

If so, then (a) every time you make a change to the DataTable from your background code, it's firing notifications from the wrong thread, which is a no-no; and (b) when you fire PropertyChanged at the end, the DataGrid might be clever enough to notice that the reference didn't actually change, so it doesn't need to do anything. (I don't know whether DataGrid tries to be that clever, but it wouldn't be unreasonable -- especially given the way WPF [constructs views on top of collections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.getdefaultview.aspx) -- and it might help explain the symptoms you're seeing.)

Try creating a new DataTable instance every time you need to refresh, and then when you're done populating that instance from your background thread, then assign the new (fully-populated) reference into your notifying property and fire PropertyChanged (and, of course, make sure to do the assignment+PropertyChanged from the UI thread).

Comment: Joe, why do I need to do this from the UI Thread? The PropertyChanged, AFAIC, already uses a dispatcher to do so...

Comment: @BrunoBrant, it seems like PropertyChanged notifications do get marshaled across threads, but I haven't actually seen documentation that says it's guaranteed, and I have seen MVVM frameworks that do the cross-thread notifications themselves. So I'm not sure how much to trust it. If you're seeing strange behavior, I'd be inclined to start by eliminating all the unknowns.

Comment: thanks for the tip. I'm marshaling it now, it seems to be able to solve the problem... But so far I've only tested it with Invoke, not BeginInvoke, which make me suspect that maybe, by using invoke, I minimize the probability of the error happening...

Answer (score 2):

Based on Asti's third point, I often come across a cross-thread PropertyChanged scenario and have a base view model for that. The view model is based on the PRISM `NotificationObject`, but of course you can implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface directly if you do not wish to use PRISM. Works just as well for Silverlight if you ever use it.

```
namespace WPF.ViewModel
{
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Threading;

    using Microsoft.Practices.Prism.ViewModel;

    /// <summary>The async notification object.</summary>
    public abstract class AsyncNotificationObject : NotificationObject
    {
        #region Constructors and Destructors

        /// <summary>Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="AsyncNotificationObject"/> class.</summary>
        protected AsyncNotificationObject()
        {
            Dispatcher = Application.Current.Dispatcher;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Properties

        /// <summary>Gets or sets Dispatcher.</summary>
        protected Dispatcher Dispatcher { get; set; }

        #endregion

        #region Methods

        /// <summary>The raise property changed.</summary>
        /// <param name="propertyName">The property name.</param>
        protected override void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (Dispatcher.CheckAccess()) base.RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName);
            else Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => base.RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName));
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Instead of directly binding the DataTable, always bind the DataView of the table. The view versions of the table, DataView has `ListChanged` and DataRowView has `PropertyChanged`.
2. WPF does support updates right down to the row level. If you change a row value, it will certainly propagate immediately.
3. `PropertyChanged` is not thread safe. You cannot cause any change to trigger `PropertyChanged` on a different thread. It must be done on the dispatcher, so have the change go through the dispatcher. 
   E.g., Instead of `Model.Data = newData`, you should use `Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(model => model.Data = newData), Model)` or similar.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Asti. I've seem in this [article](http://blog.lab49.com/archives/1166) that ClrBindingWorker already marshals the operation between threads... Does it makes sense? I'm marshalling it through Invoke, and it helps (right now, I have a memory leak that seems to be provoked by my latest change -- the introduction of the invoke -- but I have yet to confirm it).

Comment: A leak is unlikely for just using the dispatcher, though.

Comment: Asti, my thought exactly. I'm retesting the app without changes to make sure the leak wasn't introduced by the call to the dispatcher, and was already present in the application. It's hard testing though, since it takes about 18 hours of continuous operation (about 8000 consecutive calls) before the leak appears.